# A script to shrink and compress DMG disk images does not seem to work well in my scenario

Tags: command-line, disk-utility, script, dmg, compression

I'm trying to resize the ***.dmg** of my MAC OS X installation file because I have only **DVD of 4.7 GB** and not dual layer disks,at the moment. The problem is that the dmg file is almost 7 GB large and I don't know how to reduce it to **4.7 GB**. So,after some research I found a script in this web site :

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030306095219454

I run it,but I don't know really if it worked,because it has resized the original file only by 1% ! as it seems. Check by yourself the log below...

```
marks-Mac:Desktop mark$ ./dmgcon.sh Macos.dmg
Preparing imaging engine…
Reading Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)…
   (CRC32 $8E0A8B19: Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0))
Reading GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1)…
   (CRC32 $2D71B467: GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1))
Reading GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2)…
   (CRC32 $75C8939C: GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2))
Reading  (Apple_Free : 3)…
   (CRC32 $00000000:  (Apple_Free : 3))
Reading EFI System Partition (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B : 4)…
.
   (CRC32 $571DC111: EFI System Partition (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B : 4))
Reading Untitled 2 (Apple_HFS : 5)…
..............................................................................
   (CRC32 $CCE2CD3E: Untitled 2 (Apple_HFS : 5))
Reading  (Apple_Free : 6)…
..............................................................................
   (CRC32 $00000000:  (Apple_Free : 6))
Reading GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 7)…
...............................................................................
   (CRC32 $75C8939C: GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 7))
Reading GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 8)…
...............................................................................
   (CRC32 $C035E623: GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 8))
Adding resources…
...............................................................................
Elapsed Time:  5m  9.325s
File size: 6479801806 bytes, Checksum: CRC32 $1639F7E5
Sectors processed: 30556288, 12815548 compressed
Speed: 20.2Mbytes/sec
Savings: 58.6%
created: /Users/mark/Desktop/Macos.dmg.compressed.dmg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  6479801806 Dec  9 12:08 Macos.dmg
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 mark  staff  6561578523 Oct 27 08:34 Macos.dmg.bak*
```

it says : **savings 58.6%** ? if the original file is now called **Macos.dmg** and its dimensions is : **6.561.578.523 bytes (6,58 GB)**,the compressed file is : **6.479.801.806 bytes (6,48 GB)**,the difference is only of **1%** less...if everything is correct,this script is not useful at all...let me know please I have did some kind of mistake...thanks...

Comment: I'm not an expert of the mac world,so maybe I used a wrong tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compress this type of DMG for multiple reasons - so you won't have success with this scripts nor others like it. I'll suggest looking at alternative options, such as buying a dual-layer disk, or simply using a different storage medium such as a USB pen-drive or an external USB hard drive.

The reasons this type of DMG don't compress are for example:

1) Apple has already used compression on most relevant parts of the installer image - so there's not really much left to compress.

2) The disk image size is really irrelevant - the important is how much space it takes up on the DVD, and I'm afraid compressing the DMG won't change that. What you write onto the DVD is not a bit-for-bit copy of the DMG, but rather it would be uncompressed before writing onto the DMG. If not, it wouldn't be bootable nor useable for installing macOS.

Comment: ok. Can I remove something inside the dmg file that's not strictly needed and that I can install later in another way ? simply deleting files and folders ?

Comment: You cannot simply delete any files/folders, nor do I know of anything obvious you can just delete and then install later. For older versions of macOS, some enthusiasists created smaller install images, but I think that trend stopped years ago when the DVD went out of style. Which version of macOS do you want to install?

Comment: Hello. Where are you ? Do u know if there is a way to split the dmg file of a mac os mojave into two DVDs making the first one bootable and the second one contains the rest of the installation ?

Comment: OR : another way could be to convert the DMG file in ISO and then split it in two files and boot from the first one...

Comment: What do you mean - where are you? ..... And no, you cannot split the dmg or ISO into two and getting a working installer from that. Is there any particular reason why you haven't got a USB pendrive, or cannot buy one at the local super market? - It seems you're willing to go to a lot of trouble that would be completely unnecessary using such commonly available tools?

Comment: I know but only today I've got the dual layer disks. You know,I was looking for another solution because I'm very curious and nerd guy. Anyway,as soon as the dual layers disks came to my home I have burned the dmg file of the mac os inside the disk with the transmac tool and I've tried to boot it,after having configured the bios to detect only the UEFI devices. It didn't work. The BIOS of my motherboard recognizes the UEFI usb disks only sometime and until now it has never recognized the DVD. So I'm stuck.

Comment: you can read the full story here : https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/a590g8/my_gigabyte_gaz87hd3_does_not_recognize_well_the/

Comment: I see - your question is not about Macs or Apple hardware at all? - You're talking about Gigabyte motherboards, etc... so it doesn't really belong here.

Comment: in some phases of the process it is and the first part of the question is of general interest.

Comment: Well, in all the important phases - it is not. You cannot expect to burn a macOS installer on a DVD and have it just boot and work on any PC - it is designed for a Mac.

Comment: ehy man,I'm a nerd. I like to experiment. I do and after some time I come back. My goal is to learn,to enjoy myself doing odd and inusual procedures. This is my hobby. I don't do it for any commercial reason.

Comment: No matter if you're a nerd or nord, or it is a hobby or not - the computers all work the same. Hardware is not suddenly going to become compatible. You'll need very strict hardware selection in order to create a Hackintosh, and you'll need tools to ensure the correct boot sequence, drivers, etc.

Comment: it's not exactly like this,man. All computers don't work the same,because they really does not have a soul. They are tools used by people. And people can use them in a lot of creative ways,mixing and combining different kind of tools,tecniques and hardware components.

Comment: I don’t think you understand what I mean. I’m saying that there’s technical limitations that you cannot hand wave away. You cannot for example UEFI boot a BIOS-only board.

Comment: I cannot do it only because I don't know how to do it. But I'm sure that it can be done and maybe someone did it or he is doing it already.

Comment: Look - I’m not trying to hide anything from you. If you want to build a hackintosh, google it and you’ll find plenty of instructions. This is just not the forum for it. Still, some things are impossible - it’s not just because you do not know how.